# Why can`t i use a $scope value inside my controller if i can use it in my html page?

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

i have a form using angularJs, my main concern is about the select tag with ng-option
    let me give you a quick look at the form and what is going on then will explain my problem.
    note: i removed unnecessary parts like divs and classes as it is not a leyout matter.

```
<form role="form" name="feedbackForm" ng-submit="sendFeedback()" novalidate>
<!-- ---------------- SELECT ------------------->
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="approve" value="" ng-model="feedback.agree">
        <strong>May we contact you?</strong>
    </label>
    <div ng-show="feedback.agree"  ng-model="feedback.myChannel">
        <select class="form-control c-select" name="select" ng-model="feedback.myChannel" ng-options="channel.value as channel.label for channel in channels">
            <option value="">Select a method</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!-- --------------------TEEPHONE ---------------------->
    <label for="telnum">Contact Tel.</label>
    <input type="tel" id="areacode" name="areacode" ng-model="feedback.tel.areacode">
    <input type="tel" id="telnum" name="telnum" ng-model="feedback.tel.number">
    <!-- -------------  EMAIL ------------------------>
    <label for="emailid" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="feedback.email" >
```

Then i`m displaying my values as below just for develpoing purpose

```
<p> Contact by: {{ feedback.myChannel }} </p>
<p> feedback.agree: {{'( ' +  feedback.agree  + ' )'}} </p>
<p> feedback.myChannel: {{'( ' +  feedback.myChannel  + ' )'}} </p>
```

and in the controller and for the ng-option i have:

```
$scope.channels = [ 
    { value:"Tel", label:"Tel" },
    { value:"Email", label:"Email" },
    { value:"Tel & Email", label:"Tel & Email" } 
];
```

then for pushing feedback to the server i`m creating this objecgt:

```
$scope.feedback = { myChannel:"", firstName: '', lastName: '', agree: false, email: '' };
```

here are some pics to show that all those variable and values are provided to the site properly.

[image: when unchecked]
[image: email option is working]
[image: tel option is working]
[image: tel & email option is working]

My problem is:
I'm trying to use `$scope.feedback.myChannel` for other needs but I can't find on my controller whereas I'm using it in my form.

This line gives nothing. Perhaps an empty string:

```
console.log('myChannel = ' + $scope.feedback.myChannel);
```

[image: empty]

All these if s are not working and nothing shows in the console:

```
if($scope.feedback.myChannel == "Tel" || $scope.feedback.myChannel === "Tel & Email"){
    console.log($scope.feedback.myChannel);
};
if($scope.feedback.myChannel === "Email" || $scope.feedback.myChannel === "Tel & Email"){
    console.log($scope.feedback.myChannel);
};
```

This one doesn't do what it suppose to do:

```
if(!$scope.feedback.agree){ $scope.feedback.myChannel = ''; };
```

This console.log gives unexpected values:

```
console.log('1: ' + $scope.feedbackForm.myChannel)  // undefined
console.log('2: ' + $scope.feedback.myChannel);     // nothing .. perhaps an empty string
```

[image: unexpected]

Comment: Remove `ng-model` from here: `<div ng-show="feedback.agree"  ng-model="feedback.myChannel">`

Comment: Ok, I just did.. still the same.

Comment: Provide a http://plnkr.co/edit/ and copy your full code there, then we can take a look better.

Comment: Ok, will do. but for now can u tell me how to accept ur editing for my question? or it will be added by the site? Thanks.. also i uploaded about 5 pics but i can see only one is repeated.

Comment: do u think my ng-options is writing correctly?

Comment: plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/HNSQ6va5CnZWdRcVmbWs?p=preview..    my main concern is to show telephone field and email field if needed based on $scope.showTelField and $scope.showEmailField

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on your [**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/HNSQ6va5CnZWdRcVmbWs?p=preview), you're cleaning your `object` and then you try to do a `console.log()`, of course it will be a empty string.

Also:

```
console.log('1: ', $scope.feedbackForm.myChannel)
```

is **undefined**, because there's no `tag` with this `name` in your form, to call the `select` (since you named it as `name="select"`), you should to the following:

```
console.log('1: ', $scope.feedbackForm.select)
```

*Working* [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MdbbgtvQ55Yd6DoHdCCa?p=preview).

Comment: When u say im cleaning my object what did u mean?

Comment: im actually initialising an empty object then that object gets filled when select takes a value. this is my understanding .. at te submit im emptying again coz i Want a clean form avter submitting.. please let me know if thats not clear.

Comment: BTW.. ur plunker not showing the values inside the console as i expect.

Comment: Well, as I said you're setting all properties of your object to `''` and after it you try to `console.log()` your variable.. how can it show your the value if you cleaned it????? Also, how can it not showing the values that you're expecting? If you want to see only the selected option in your select.. then change to `consle.log(feedback.myChannel)`, there's no problem.

Comment: thank you .. how am i emptying my object am actually creating it as an empty object which should take it`s values from the form itself.  When i console.log .. i lnow it is going to be empty string but my question is .. after i select an option on the form why the $scope.veedback.myChannel still empty while it is showing on the right side of html page as u can see

Comment: Here is a simple controller on plunker  ..   http://plnkr.co/edit/HNSQ6va5CnZWdRcVmbWs?p=preview

Comment: It's not empty man.. as I said it's only empty because you're cleaning it.

Comment: ok, why is it still  empty after you select a channel (an option from select)?

Comment: in a very simple way.. how can you console.log your selection?

Comment: Man.. I said 3 times, you're trying to `console.log()` after cleaning your fields, how can it print anything????????? Just move the `console.log()` to before your cleaning. Take a look man..... http://plnkr.co/edit/WFzqU2P7S6ODnDgbHvA9?p=preview

Comment: with respect your not making any point here ceck console at line 8 , 23 ov ur plunker tey give noting too .. so where is ur solution?

Comment: select an option please and show me console.log($scope.feedback.myChannel)

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but I think you're kidding me.. man.. in **line 8** you have a **BLANK** string, how do you want to print anything? In line 23, **AFTER** submit you should get something!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117786/discussion-between-shireef-khatab-and-developer033).

Comment: aha.. i was wrong about console coz it is not two ways data binding ..  so i got ur point,     but u still didnt get mine.. let's have this little challenge here.. .. ill give a link to plunker where i want to show the the telephone field and the email field based on a scope values.. so easy right? ng-show..!   let's see how r u gonna do it .. this drove me mad all day yesterday and it is actually my first question before the console battle..    :) http://plnkr.co/edit/L12ltpi27VAIDkFHKHwX?p=preview